# Why is it common to grow microalgae in bottles or canisters?

Tags: microbiology, food, agriculture

I came across many people growing Chlorella or Spirulina types of microalgae, inside bottles or canisters and that that they also bubbled CO<sub>2</sub> into these containers artificially.

This question is basically comprised of two questions that will clarify what I am trying to understand:

- Why do they use bottles or any type of bottle-like canister?
- Why do they insert CO2 to the bottle artificially in cases the bottle doesn't have a cork ? If the claim is that enough CO2 won't be able to get through the bottle neck than why growing the algae inside a bottle\aquarium in the first place, and not in a tub with full exposure to the air?

Comment: Simple answer from http://justspirulina.org/spirulina-manual/ "Spirulina needs sunlight so it is preferable that the container in which it is grown be transparent. Empty, clear soft drink or water bottles (at least 1.5 litre) are a good option."

Comment: @Benia I cannot find anything about "they insert CO2 to the bottle artificially" in the links provided by you.

Comment: The thin tubes they insert, aren't these splitting CO2 into the water (as the bottle is sealed for CO2 entrance) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, the credit for this answer goes to [another 'Homo sapien'](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/19099/another-homo-sapien) from the [Spirulina manual](http://justspirulina.org/spirulina-manual/) link in his comment.

> **Why do they use bottles or any type of bottle-like canister?**

Likely, because they are clear. From the manual:

> Spirulina needs sunlight so it is preferable that the container in which it is grown be transparent.

Plastic bottles are cheap, clear, and easy to come by, so they make the ideal material.

> **Why do they insert CO2 to the bottle artificially in cases the bottle doesn't have a cork?**

I don't think the tubes in your picture are CO2 tubes. Rather, I'd bet they are bubble tubes (like in aquariums). These are necessary to keep the growth medium moving constantly. Again, from the manual:

> Spirulina tends to gather at the top of the growing culture, where sunlight exposure is maximal. Due to this, Spirulina that cannot reach the top will not multiply and will ultimately die.
>
> In order to maximize Spirulina exposure to sunlight, the water in which it is grown must be stirred
> ...
>
> *Another option is a pump, the simplest kind used for aquariums.*
> (emphasis mine)

Comment: Luigi, a small question, aren't at least some aquariums have CO2 tubes sometimes? I mean aren't some types of Fish or Algae hat does need extra CO2 into the water in some other cases?

Comment: BTW please thumb up if you liked the question - If you would, I could thumb up your answer...

Comment: @Benia I already have. And regarding the aquarium question, I'm not an expert on fish or algae, but I always thought the purpose of the tubes into aquariums was to move the water/make it more accessible for gas exchange, so that the oxygen/CO2 in the water could be closer to atmospheric levels (you don't want to suffocate your fish). While I'm sure there are specific organisms that prefer low CO2, I feel like most everything has evolved to grow best at atmospheric concentrations of O2/CO2

Comment: @Benia I do not think there would be any fish or algae that would have evolved to live by getting extra CO2 from artificial source. You see, as Luigi said, most organisms are adapted to live with natural atmospheric conditions (except, maybe, thermophiles which live near volcanic vents in deep sea surface).

Comment: Well, according to what you said guys I know understand that this tubes insert some fresh air to the water and the excessive Oxygen or CO2 / any other air-material will just leave the water out through the bottle-neck (and open area if there is no cork) and thus will just split the algae in a more efficient way and avoid formation of a single light-hiding layer of algae in the outermost areas of the canister... I hope I understand you well guys, this is very helping for me and I am very grateful for you for your help !!!

Comment: @Luigi While you certainly can grow aquatic plants with atomospheric CO2 levels, they don't necessarily "grow best" at that level - a fair number of people with planted tanks will supplement the CO2, sometimes with rather [elaborate rigs](http://www.drsfostersmith.com/fish-supplies/aquarium-freshwater-specific/aquarium-carbon-dioxide-injection/ps/c/3578/27696/3747), to increase the growth rate of the plants. If you're attempting to produce microalgae in bulk, it might be reasonable to supplement the CO2 to increase the amount you're producing.